# What is the difference between "includes" and "contain" in Java class association

Tags: java

Here is the design specification,

> Classes :
>
> - EmployeeRecord
> - Employee
> - Employees
> - AppDriver
>
> Class Associations :
>
> - EmployeeRecord(1) - includes - (1)Employee
> - Employees(1) - contains - (m)Employee
> - AppDriver(1) - uses (1) Employees

I am trying to understand the relation among these 4 classes to start my assignment. I am assuming AppDriver acts like main, Employees is to return a collection of Employee(array), and EmployeeRecord includes data(work hour, pay rate etc.) of each Employee.

Screenshot of the design specification :

[image: Screenshot of design specification]

Comment: There is no link here...

Comment: [link] https://imgur.com/gallery/6M6b55M

Comment: And just wondering: isn't your assignment coming with some education material that explains the terms used in the assignment (as I am a bit wondering if there is really a meaningful difference between the two words).

Comment: Unfortunately, the design specification is given as a PDF document, I tried to convert it to text using online tool, but it loses all the format.

Comment: It might be enough to improve the formatting of the text elements you already have in your question.

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Post the code instead, formatted as code.

Comment: This is Java specific, please remove the `uml` tag as this has absolutely nothing to do with UML.

Comment: "Employees is to return a collection of Employee (array)" -- NO! The "(-) Employee[] emps" specification implies that the Employees class should hold a private array of employees, but not expose it. Instead, it has methods for adding and retrieving individual employees. Also, the spec shows that Employee holds a reference to an instance of EmployeeRecord. That's all that "includes" means in this context (it's not a generally well-defined term).

Comment: Also, in the real world you should not use float to hold monetary amounts. Use BigDecimal instead. Your assignment tells you to use float though, so you'd better do that, but remember not to use float for monetary amounts if/when you get a Java programming job.

Comment: Hi! The difference is that 'contains' refers to 'aggregation' and 'includes' to 'association'.
"In aggregation, the contained classes are not strongly dependent on the lifecycle of the container." Every 'Employee' will remain intact if 'Employees' is dissolved, but if 'Employee' ceases to exist, 'Employee' will cease too.
EmployeeRecord will contain a reference.